# is there a fabric8 API (for kubernetes) to watch events associated w/ a service and find its public IP?

Tags: service, kubernetes, fabric8

I recently started working on a code base that uses  fabric8  to manage containers, pods, 
services, etc.  in kubernetes.

After creating a service for a given pod, I need to inform our end users of the external
IP via which they can access said service.

From the command line (kubectl), I would do a  describe, and get output like this

```
kubectl  describe  service   spark-master
    Name:           spark-master
    Namespace:      5683616f16426028459a535c
    Labels:         group=krylov-dev,name=spark-master
    Selector:       name=spark-master
    Type:           LoadBalancer
    IP:         10.0.0.103
    Port:           7077    7077/TCP
    NodePort:       7077    31988/TCP
    Endpoints:      172.17.0.2:7077
    Port:           7070    7070/TCP
    NodePort:       7070    32539/TCP
    Endpoints:      172.17.0.2:7070  <<- this is what i want!
    Session Affinity:   None
    No events.
```

I used wireshark to trace the REST API calls that were being made when the above
command runs, and it seems the raw Kubernetes REST API accesses the above info via a URL 
like this

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/my_namespace_whatever/endpoints/spark-master
```

So, I could theoretically get the info I want via the raw Kubernetes REST API. But since we 
are using fabric8, I would prefer to stick to that if there is any way to accomplish this
with their API.

I see that there is class that carries info about endpoints in fabric8
( io.fabric8.kubernetes.api.model.Endpoints),  but I searched and could find no documentation 
on how to query a service for its Endpoints information.

Also, when using the fabric8 API to watch for events we have tried
looking at service.getStatus.getLoadBalancer.getIngress() (whenever we get 
a an event associated with our service), but this  is always empty ;^(

would be most grateful for any tips or guidance....
    -chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fabric8 client has the following API call:

`client.endpoints().get();`

This would give you the list of all end points. Now there are ways in which you can limit the list that you receive to a particular namespace/labels using:

`client.endpoints().inNamespace("5683616f16426028459a535c").withLabel("name", "spark-master").list();`

Comment: Thanks, Vijay !   btw:  where can i find the javadocs for this stuff?.   /cb